# C++ why is inheritance not working?

Tags: c++, inheritance

In Shape.hpp:

```
class Shape {   
    public:
    char c;
    virtual void paint();
    ...
};
```

In Triangle.hpp:

```
#include "Shape.hpp"

class Triangle : public Shape {
    ...
};
```

In Triangle.cpp:

```
...

void Triangle::paint() {
    ...
}

...
```

When compiling:

```
error: class ‘Triangle’ does not have any field named ‘c’
error: no ‘void Triangle::paint()’ member function declared in class ‘Triangle’
```

I do not understand why Triangle doesn't have the fields and member functions of its parent class, Shape. How can this be fixed?

Comment: You never declared any `paint` function in `Triangle`. Any C++ polymorphism resource should have nice working examples.

Comment: Your `class Triangle` definition is missing a `;` after the closing brace.

Comment: @pmr It was only a mistake here, not in the code. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare the `paint()` member function in `Triangle` too:

```
class Triangle : public Shape 
{
 public:
    void paint() override;
};
```

Comment: Indeed, this solved the problem with the member function. What about the field c?

Comment: @user2460978 You should post some code that reproduces the `c` problem.

Comment: @juanchopanza I selected the part of the code relevant to the problem. I'm not getting any other compiler error other than this, either.

Comment: @user2460978 There is no way any error related to `c` could be reproduced from your code, unless you really are missing a `;` at the end of your class definitions.

Comment: @juanchopanza would this change if c was not type char but an instance of a class? i.e. "Color c;" instead of "char c;"

Comment: In the constructor of Triangle, I changed from using initialization lists to not using them, and now the compile error has changed to linking errors: "undefined reference to 'vtable for Shape'", as well as "undefined reference to 'typeinfo for Shape'". I shall investigate this.

Answer (score 2):

Declaration of overriding function is needed in derived class too:

```
class Triangle : public Shape 
{
 public:
    void paint();
};
```

optionally, in C++11 you can be more explicit with:

```
class Triangle : public Shape 
{
 public:
    void paint() override;
};
```

Then the compiler also knows that it's an override, so can "check" that you are not altering/adding new functions that you think are overrides.